# sending file with retrofit 2 which file name is contain Persian character

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, multipart

I'm sending `multipart` requests with retrofit and it works fine. but when my file name is contain Persian character ,my app crashes and i get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x62f at 35 in
>   Content-Disposition value: form-data; name="photo";
>   filename="دوچرخه.jpg"

this is how i send my multipart request:

```
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

    ProgressRequestBody fileBody = new ProgressRequestBody(imageFile, this);
    MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", imageFile.getName(), fileBody);

    RetroInterface retroInterface = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetroInterface.class);
    Call<SendFileResponse> call = retroInterface.sendPhoto(token, myHashmap, filePart);
```

how can I fix this issue?!

Answer (score 2):

My not perfect solution, becouse it can change some characters, is to put `URLEncoder.encode(file.name, "utf-8")` instead of plain name.

Comment: Will this solution work for any file name containing wild characters?

Comment: this solution will work for the retrofit to send request but the server might have issue with that encoding, I am having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **`addUnsafeNonAscii()`** method from `Header.Builder` class by which we can add a header with the specified name and value. Does validation of header names, allowing non-ASCII values. So we can pass any language characters as an value including persian character too.

```
val fileName = "your file name with extention"
val reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), File(imageDir))

val header = Headers.Builder()
header.addUnsafeNonAscii("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"$fileName")

val body = MultipartBody.Part.create(header.build(), reqFile)
myApi.uploadItem(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion though but as a workaround you try renaming the file to an id (timestamp / anything else) for the filename and add a name field that will contain the actual name if the file...

```
public class Object {
  private String filename;
  private File actualFile;
}
```

That way when retrieving later you can still always have reference to the file you want.

Comment: I've used your way, but I think there must be a proper way for handling it!